# countdown timer should continue for two php pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-applications, countdowntimer

this is the code for countdown timer

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var hoursleft = 0;
var minutesleft = 10;           // you can change these values to any value greater than 0
var secondsleft = 0;
var millisecondsleft = 0;
var finishedtext = "Countdown finished!" // text that appears when the countdown reaches 0
end = new Date();

end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes()+minutesleft);
end.setSeconds(end.getSeconds()+secondsleft);
end.setMilliseconds(end.getMilliseconds()+millisecondsleft);
function cd(){
    now = new Date();
    diff = end - now;
    diff = new Date(diff);
    var msec = diff.getMilliseconds();
    var sec = diff.getSeconds();
    var min = diff.getMinutes();

    if (min < 10){
        min = "0" + min;
    }
    if (sec < 10){
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }
    if(msec < 10){
        msec = "00" +msec;
    }
    else if(msec < 100){
        msec = "0" +msec;
    }
    if(now >= end){
        clearTimeout(timerID);
        document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML = finishedtext;
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec;
    }       // you can leave out the + ":" + msec if you want...
            // If you do so, you should also change setTimeout to setTimeout("cd()",1000)
    timerID = setTimeout("cd()", 10); 
}
window.onload = cd;
//-->
</script>
```

I want this timer to continue for two php pages without restarting again. When each question displays the timer should not restart again.
test1.php page have all multiple choice question to answer and test2.php page have all fill in the blank questions to answer. In my application first test1.php (i.e MCQs) will run and after all MCQs test2.php will run. How can i use same timer for both pages.

Comment: Take a look at JavaScripts `localStorage` or at the PHP sessions

Comment: try to paste html code of timer in both php file and put this script in a file with name.js and then include it in both file.

Comment: @anant   I did what you said but still the timer starts again

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck with a similar kind of issue right now in PHP and worked out a solution. I am not sure if the following helps, but try if this works for you.

Save the start time as a session variable
Before each question displays, perform an if function to update the diff as difference between "end" and "Session["time"]".

```
if(Session["time"]) {
    if(Session["time"]) < end {
        diff = end - Session["time"];
    } else {
         //perform answer submission (may be).
         }
} else {
    var d = new Date();
    Session["time"] = d.getTime();
}
```